# Examples of Exp tool to export data from Oracle db table to text file

Tags: oracle

I need to export data from an Oracle database and then import the data to another oracle database. To import data, I can use SQLLDR tool to load a flat text file. To do that, I have to generate this flat text file from a Oracle database table first.

Are there any examples to use this tool? I need to pass Oracle database name, schema name with user/pwd, table name, constrains, and date time column format information to generate a text file. This text file will be used by SQLLDR tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using EXP/IMP or EXPDP/IMPDP if transferring from one Oracle database to another. They are covered in the [Utilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/toc.htm) manual

If you MUST use a CSV file, the [unloader tool](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/z?p_url=ASKTOM%2Edownload_file%3Fp_file%3D6551135514501758779&p_cat=unloader15a.sql&p_company=822925097021874) on the [AskTom site](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:8:0::NO). But be careful to check dates/timestamps and any exotic datatypes.